# python AttributeError: class XXX has no attribute '__class__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror

Who can help me with this Exception?

```
 File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 305, in _compile_for_args
argtypes.append(self.typeof_pyval(a))
File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 429, in typeof_pyval
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typing/typeof.py", line 28, in typeof
ty = typeof_impl(val, c)
File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/singledispatch.py", line 210, in wrapper
return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
AttributeError: class FeatureEncoding has no attribute '__class__'
```

Comment: hi add your code please

Comment: Apparently you're doing as the error message says: you're accessing the `__class__` attribute on the first command-line argument (`args[0]`) which is not present. It's impossible to debug this without the offending code.

Comment: Going by the traceback, this seems like a bug. Try upgrading to the latest version of whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every instance has a `__class__` attribute. Just a general recommendation: In most cases it's better to use `type` instead of `__class__` nevertheless.

For example old-style classes don't have a class:

```
>>> class A:
...   pass
...
>>> A.__class__
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__class__'

>>> int.__class__  # just for comparison the class of the int class
<type 'type'>
```

But `type` works:

```
>>> type(A)
<type 'classobj'>
```

Note: instances of old-style classes have the `__class__` attribute

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__class__
<class __main__.A at 0x0000000002E61168>
```